# Kannada font issue in pdf genration with itext

Tags: java, itext

I have tried to use Itext5 and Itext7 in my application to generate Kannada(Indian language) PDF document. But the character joins are not coming properly

iText7:

```
String dir = "D:\\test\\sample pdf file\\itext7\\itext7pdf_" +System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf";

File licenseFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:license/itextkey1567154651327_0.xml");
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(licenseFile.getAbsolutePath());

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fos);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:font/tunga.ttf");
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(file.getAbsolutePath(),PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
document.add(new Paragraph().setFont(font)
        .add("\u0CAA\u0CCD\u0CAF\u0CBE\u0CB0\u0CBE\u0CAE\u0CC0\u0C9F\u0CB0\u0CCD \u0CAA\u0CCD\u0CB0\u0C95\u0CBE\u0CB0\u0C97\u0CB3\u0CA8\u0CCD\u0CA8\u0CC1 \u0CAA\u0CA1\u0CC6\u0CAF\u0CC1\u0CB5\u0CBE\u0C97 \u0CA6\u0CCB\u0CB7"));
document.close();
```

The expected output is
ಪ್ಯಾರಾಮೀಟರ್ ಪ್ರಕಾರಗಳನ್ನು ಪಡೆಯುವಾಗ ದೋಷ
but I got words like in the link
https://ibb.co/2sbxV6B

Comment: Are you using the itext 7 *pdfCalligraph* add on?

Comment: Actually I need to use itext5 and its not working. So I have tried with itext7 and added pdfCalligraph as dependency

Comment: pdfCalligraph is necessary for non-trivial scripts. Whether it suffices, I cannot tell. You might want ask itext support.

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late on answering this question but for future references, I am writing my solution here, on adding following dependencies to pom.xml and updating version of iText7-core & html2pdf dependencies works for me

- Add below repository to your pom.xml

```
<!-- All add-ons and iText 7 core-->
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>itext</id>
    <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

- Add the pdfCalligraph dependency to .pom project file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>typography</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```